# Place an image inside of a google maps marker icon

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, parse-platform

Currently the markers on my Google Maps Map view appear to look like the first picture I uploaded, however I need to find a way to add a thumbnail in the center of the image similar to the second view,  I am unsure of how to do this as the thumbnail is dynamic so I cannot set it to a specific image like I am doing by setting the marker.icon to the icons bubble image.  Has anybody attempted anything like this before?  The thumbnails are being retrieved from a Parse server so I cannot prepare this ahead of time with code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a project a while back. What I did to solve it, was in the javascript I started by making all the markers set to be hidden initially. As I added each one I added an eventListener to the src of the icon image so that when it loaded I could switch the marker on with setAnimation("BOUNCE") to make it look intentional. That's the idea and it worked for me. Let me know if you run into any bumps.